# Whether the sentence is the inversion type or not?

Tags: inversion

I ran across a sentence from the magazine 'Esquire' through the internet. I'd like to know whether the sentence is the inversion type or not.

> Always  does he throw the disorder into everything he does.

Comment: Are you sure that sentence came from Esquire Magazine? It has a number of errors that would not normally be made by English speakers. Perhaps it has some (very) unusual context? ... Or part of a joke?

Comment: Thanks, Lorel C. I found it on ngram, typing  'Always does he'.

Comment: Could you provide a hyperlink to the source?

Comment: @Sam...



Esquire - Volume 47 - Page 56 1957
> Always does he throw the disorder into everything he does. And always does he come to fall back on me.

Comment: @theinlwin , the hyperlink is incomplete, it doesn't go to the snippet. An idea could be - edit the question, provide more of the surrounding text. In any case, based on "And always does he come to fall back on me." that looks like poetry, which means that artistic or poetic license allows the writer to use non-grammatical constructions. Poetry is not the best place to learn as a foreign speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, well, it's *poetry*, is it? Didn't think of that, did I?

To answer your question, yes, the sentence uses inverted word order.

With the usual, typical, word order the sentence would be:

> He always throws the disorder into everything he does.

But the poet has decided to start with the adverb "always", maybe to emphasize his main point, or some other poetic reason. So he inverts the sentence (simple present tense changes from "throws" to "does throw"), and it changes into the sentence you see in your question.

I still don't understand what he means by "the disorder" though. Does he mean "chaos"? ["Disorder" with*out* "the".] Or a specific instance of chaos? [*the* disorder.] Or maybe it is a disease?

Context would tell. Anyway, as others have noted, poetry is not a reliable place to find examples of normal English.